# Openrowset function failure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, openrowset, aceoledb

I'm executing this openrowset function:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 
    'Excel 12.0;Database=C:\Users\JCPABALAN\Desktop\Data Migration\ListOfDiscards.xlsx;HDR=YES', 
    'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')
```

But it gave me the following error

> OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" returned message "The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object 'Sheet1$'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly. If 'Sheet1$' is not a local object, check your network connection or contact the server administrator.".
>   Msg 7350, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   Cannot get the column information from OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)".

I have already set the `Ad Hoc Distributed Queries` into 1 and I Installed `Microsoft ACE` and also executed this line of code:

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'AllowInProcess', 1 
GO 
EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'DynamicParameters', 1 
GO
```

But it still won't work.

Comment: Is the path "C:\Users\JC..." on the same computer as the SQL Server? Does the SQL Server service account have access to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You Error message has two parts :

> OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" returned message "The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object 'Sheet1$'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly. If 'Sheet1$' is not a local object, check your network connection or contact the server administrator.".

And

> Msg 7350, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   Cannot get the column information from OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)".

That the second part is because of error of first part, So your main error is at first part, that tells us:

> The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object 'Sheet1$'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly. If 'Sheet1$' is not a local object, check your network connection or contact the server administrator.

Some common causes and solutions are these:

- **Path not exists :** File or Path `C:\Users\JCPABALAN\Desktop\Data Migration\ListOfDiscards.xlsx` is not exist;

> **Note :** SQL Server `C:\` is referring to the `\\Server\C$`, So if you are using SSMS and you register a `Server` and are connecting to it, your path is not exist.

- **File permission is denied :** File or Path `C:\Users\JCPABALAN\Desktop\Data Migration\ListOfDiscards.xlsx` have security level that you can access them from SQL Server service account, You can grant access to SQL Server service account.
- **Sheet Name is invalid :** Worksheet `Sheet1` is not a valid sheet name in your workbook sheets, You maybe change its name.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @shA.t

Comment: File is exported on server. If you wish to export on other PC, check this answer ( it's about database backup file, but principle is the same) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16491/restore-database-backup-over-the-network/20465401